# How to integrate Prolog within a Web application?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a Web application for which I think Prolog would be interesting to apply rules and solve constraints. Let's say that this is an application about recommending movies to a user based on the user's preferences + a set of global relations/facts about movies. For instance a global `movie_genre(terminator, action).` and for one user `likes_genres(alice, [action, comedy]).` and for another user `likes_genres(bob, [thriller, drama]).`, so maybe `suggest_movie(alice, Movie).` would return `Movie = terminator`.

I was thinking of having a main back-end in another language using a framework (like PHP or Node.js) and calling the Prolog back-end when needed. However, I'm not sure how to proceed. How would you:

- store data: usually, I would store data in a relational database. But from what I understand, I could also store facts with asserta/z and remove them with retract? But then, is it scalable to load all facts for all users? Or would I load facts for a given user?
- call the Prolog back-end: Run a Prolog HTTP server? Start the interpreter when needed?
- do request/get responses, in particular when there are several responses: using a higher-level protocol, or instrumenting the Prolog interpreter?

Any help or advice is appreciated, thanks!

Additional notes:

1. I know there was a similar question, but it was asked literally a decade ago. Times have changed, and perhaps the answers could be different today.
2. I know there are libraries implementing Prolog, and I prefer using a full (ISO compliant) Prolog interpreter.
3. Performance is not a primary concern at this point, development speed is!